# Shallow Copy with Structs in C

Tags: c, struct, shallow-copy

Let's say you have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
} Child;

typedef struct {
    int age;
    Child firstChild;
} Parent;

int main() {
    Parent p1 = {5, {3}};
    Parent p2 = p1;
}
```

When you copy `p1` to `p2`, are you performing a shallow copy on both fields or only the `Child` field? My guess is that `age` is copied by value, but `firstChild` is shallow copied.

Comment: The copy here is not shallow at all. Both structures will have their own copies of all the fields with identical values. Stucture assignment is pretty similar to `memcpy`-ing one to the other.

Comment: There are no pointers here, so there's no such thing as a "deep" copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything will be copied except (perhaps) alignment bits.

When you have pointers, then the *value* of the pointer will be copied (the address), not what they point to. This is what you could call "shallow".

Comment: Does standard says member by member copy or just a `memcopy`? And what happens for uninitialized members?

Comment: @TruthSeeker: The Standard grants implementations enormous latitude on the presumption that they will use it to best serve their customers.  It states that a struct copy may arbitrarily copy or ignore padding, and more significantly fails to specify what may happen if a struct being copied has uninitialized members.

Comment: @supercat: As I got to know from other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113134/4139593) it is  UB in CPP, but didn't find relevant info from [C 
INTERNATIONAL STANDARD](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Contents)