# Does separating allocation from initialization in this way cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

Does the following separation of declaration/allocation from initialization result in undefined behavior?

```cpp
#include <new>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
T Uninitialized()
{
    alignas(T) char bytes[sizeof(T)];
    return std::forward<T>(*(T*)(void*)(&bytes));
}

template<typename T>
T ZeroInitialized()
{
    alignas(T) char bytes[sizeof(T)] = {};
    return std::forward<T>(*(T*)(void*)(&bytes));
}

struct S
{
    char c = 1;
};

int main()
{
    // This arrangement lets us defer (or skip!) construction of
    // these stack-allocated variables.

    S sU = Uninitialized<S>();
    S sZ = ZeroInitialized<S>();
    {
        // Note that without using placement new, the destructors of
        // sU and sZ would be invoked at the end of this block scope
        // AND at the end of `main`.

        new (&sU) S();
        new (&sZ) S();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

UBSan doesn't object, but that isn't a guarantee of correctness.

---

(edit) related discussions:

[Copying structs with uninitialized members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112841/copying-structs-with-uninitialized-members)

[Is circumventing a class' constructor legal or does it result in undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644977/is-circumventing-a-class-constructor-legal-or-does-it-result-in-undefined-behav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This arrangement lets us defer (or skip!) construction of
> these stack-allocated variables.

No, it does not. Both allocation functions move constructs `T`:

```
return std::forward<T>(*(T*)(void*)(&bytes));
//                     ^
```

Given that it does so from a plain buffer of bytes, constructing a non-POD `T` will make it have undefined behavior. In the `Uninitialized` version it will not matter if it's a POD since it'll read from uninitialized memory and therefore have undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I guess there's just no conformant way to declare a non-fundamental, non-pointer variable without invoking a constructor.

Comment: @Zaaier You're welcome! Well, you can allocate space for it but if you `return` a `T`, a constructor will be used. If you instead return the buffer (as `std::array<char, sizeof(T)>`) you can use that to construct your `T`s later [example](https://godbolt.org/z/88ETxj9vM)