# Must lvalues of type T identify objects of type T? If `p` has type `T *`, does `&*p` require `p` to actually point to an object of type `T`?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, dereference

In C++, given `ST *p`, `*p` produces an lvalue ([expr.unary.op#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1)), and if the static type `ST` is primitive converting `*p` to an rvalue actually *accesses* and *reads* `*p` ([conv.lval](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval), [basic.lval#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)). But suppose we *don't* convert `*p` to an rvalue. We can evaluate `&*p`, or bind a reference to `*p`, etc. `p` must still point to an object or function of *dynamic* type `DT`.
Must `ST` be somehow related to `DT`? Strictly speaking, rules `&*p` might even require `ST = DT`, but that's absurd because it's more restrictive than rules about actual accesses! Quoting [expr.unary.op#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*. Its operand shall be a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”, where `T` is an object or function type. The operator yields an lvalue of type `T` denoting the object or function to which the operand points.

Hence the title question: Must lvalues of type `T` point to objects of type `T`? "Clearly not", I think, but does the standard answer this anywhere?

---

I expect `&*p` must be less restrictive than accessing `*p`, and can be more restrictive than evaluating `p` — and those cases have clearer rules:

1. accessing pointers has strict requirements ("strict aliasing"): actual accesses are only defined behavior if static type `ST` belongs to a certain list of types; this list includes *more* than dynamic type `DT`; specifically, `ST` can be `DT`, its signed/unsigned variants, and `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` ([basic.lval#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)).
2. pointers themselves have no such requirement: if we just evaluate pointer `p` itself, static type `ST` and dynamic type `DT` need not be related, because a `static_cast` from `void*` to an arbitrary type has defined behavior *if alignment requirements are satisfied* ([expr.static.cast#14](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#14)).

---

Note: according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21053756/53974, it seems (only?) expected that `p` points to an object or function.

---

EDIT: For concreteness, consider function `f` below.

```
#include <iostream>

short* f(int *ip) { // assume `p` actually points to DT = int
  void *vp = ip;
  // ^^ legal, per https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#2

  short* sp = static_cast<short*> (vp);
  // legal, per [expr.static.cast#14]
  return &*sp;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i = 0;
    short* sp = f(&i);
    void* vp = sp;
    int* ip = static_cast<int*>(vp);
    *ip = 1;
    std::cout << "I: " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Must lvalues of type T point to objects of type T?* What?  An object of type `T` doesn't point to a `T`, it is a `T`

Comment: If `DT` is unrelated to `ST`, how did you make `p` point to `DT` in the first place? Most likely, you've invoked undefined behavior at that point. Can you show some code illustrating what you have in mind?

Comment: The current draft has removed a sentence that was in C++17, " If the type of the expression is “pointer to T ”, the type of the result is “ T ”". There must be a PR behind that change that might give some rationale.  I have certainly seen it argued in the past that the behaviour is undefined by omission if the lvalue is evaluated at such time as there is not an object of type `T` at the designated location

Comment: @NathanOliver Typo, yes, so I fixed that to "identify" — I can use "determine the identity" if you prefer https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.1.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added some code but no, a cast from `void*` doesn't need UB if you respect alignment requirements.

Comment: @M.M not removed, but changed to not to misuse «result». _I have certainly seen it argued in the past that the behaviour is undefined by omission if the lvalue is evaluated at such time as there is not an object of type `T` at the designated location_ I think you are confusing with UB by omission for `*` applied to a null pointer, because [expr.unary.op]/1 says «lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points», which does not apply in this case. This «implicit UB» interpretation still apply to the current draft wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted passage does not impose any requirement on the (dynamic) type of the object in question.  If you initialize

```
int i;
auto &r=*reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&i);
```

the result of the cast refers to `i` despite having the type `unsigned*`, and similarly `r` is an lvalue of type `unsigned` that refers to the **`int`** object `i` (not undefined behavior from trying to refer to a nonexistent `unsigned` object at that address).  Accessing `i` via that lvalue is blessed by [basic.lval]/11 (as mentioned), although the standard fails to indicate the actual **effects** of such access.  (Presumably the bit pattern is used/updated, but there are subtleties when, say, the bytes of a pointer variable are mutated through a `char` lvalue.)