# Sequence Point and Evaluation Order( Preincrement)

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

There was a debate today among some of my colleagues and I wanted to clarify it. It is about the evaluation order and the sequence point in an expression. It is clearly stated in the standard that C/C++ does not have a left-to-right evaluation in an expression unlike languages like Java which is guaranteed to have a sequencial left-to-right order. So, in the below expression, the evaluation of the leftmost operand(B) in the binary operation is sequenced before the evaluation of the rightmost operand(C):

```
A = B B_OP C
```

The following expression according, to [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) under the subsection *Sequenced-before rules(Undefined Behaviour)* and Bjarne's TCPPL 3rd ed, is an UB

```
x = x++ + 1;
```

It could be interpreted as the compilers like BUT the expression below is said to be clearly a well defined behaviour in C++11

```
x = ++x + 1;
```

So, if the above expression is well defined, **what is the "fate" of this**?

```
array[x] = ++x;
```

It seems the evaluation of a post-increment and post-decrement is not defined but the pre-increment and the pre-decrement is defined.

NOTE: **This is not used in a real-life code.** Clang 3.4 and GCC 4.8 clearly warns about both the pre- and post-increment sequence point.

Comment: In `x = ++x + 1`, the value of `x` on the LHS is not used, therefore it is not UB. OTOH, in `array[x] = ++x`, the value *is* used, therefore UB (as it's not sequenced wrt the modification in `++x`).

Comment: `C/C++` is not a language. The rules are slightly different for C than for C++. (Also, the rules for C11 differ from C99; and C++11 differs from C++03).

Comment: [Link to discussion of x = ++x + 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005508/so-why-is-i-i-1-well-defined-in-c11)

Answer (score 5):

Lets see what the standard says about sequencing:

> C++11 5.17/1: the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.

So the evaluation of the operands `array[x]` and `++x` are *not* sequenced with respect to each other. Both use the value of `x`, and one modifies it, giving undefined behaviour.

(The second example differs by not using the value of `x` in the left operand; it remains an *lvalue*).

Comment: If I get the explanation correctly: in both cases(x = ++x + 1 and array[x] = ++x ), the values of *x* in the RHS is read but the side effects is delayed until the value computation and side effects of the LHS operands of the assignment operator. **array[x]** theoretically doesn't *commit its changes* yet, so changes to x shouldn't change the behaviour of the read memory.

Answer (score 0):

In `array[x] = ++x;`, there are two value computations on the scalar object `x`, and one side effect on `x`.

The value computation of `++x` is sequenced relative to its side effect, but the value computation of `x` in `array[x]` is not sequenced relative to the side effect of `++x`.

So the behavior is undefined.

The difference between `x = ++x` and `array[x] = ++x` is that in the former the appearance of `x` on the LHS is subject to side effect, while in the latter the `x` on the LHS is subject to  value computation.

Comment: Arguably, `x = ++x` also contains two value computations. [intro.execution]/15 states UB if one value computation *uses the value* of the scalar object (and another one modifies it).

Comment: Spelling this out a bit more, "evaluating" a glvalue (i.e. the left-hand side in this expression) means determining where the memory location is in which the newly-assigned value will be stored.  So if the l.h.s is `x`, we already know `x`'s address; we don't depend on the value of `x`. But in `array[x]` we must retrieve the value of `x` to find out which memory location is designated.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Huh? Why should `x = ++x` be UB while `x = ++x + 1` is not?

Comment: @dyp see AndreyT's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005508/so-why-is-i-i-1-well-defined-in-c11)

Comment: @MattMcNabb the side effect of assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the RHS, which is (in this case) sequenced after the side effect of the RHS.

Comment: @ecatmur the side-effect of incrementing `x` is not part of the value computation of the RHS (for `x = ++x` or `x = x++ + 1`); it is unsequenced w.r.t the assignment side-effect. [Further discussion in this DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#637)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The side-effect of `++x` is sequenced before the value computation of `++x` (effectively, because the value computation of an assignment is sequenced after its side-effect), and the value computation of the RHS of `=` (i.e., of `++x`) is sequenced before the side-effect of `=`.

Comment: @dyp Please provide a reference as you are contradicting the references I posted in earlier comments, which hold that it is only the use of `++i` as operand of binary-`+` which causes the side-effect to be sequenced-before

Comment: Now this is getting confusing, if
    x = ++x;
is a UB, why isn't
    x = ++x + 1;
At least there are 2 value computation, but the side effect of the RHS operand is sequenced after the side effect of LHS operand??? What on earth is the difference?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Unfortunately, I don't exactly see where this is claimed in texts you cited. When lvalue-to-rvalue conversion must be applied is not rigorously specified in the Standard, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5099769 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1642 Additionally, the Standard uses the sequencing rules to state where UB happens in these kind of cases. And the sequencing rules are rather clear: The value computation of `++x` in `x = ++x` is sequenced before the side-effect of `=`, and the value of the LHS is not used => no sequencing issues.

Comment: @Josh the difference is that when `++x` is used as operand of `+`, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed, which (apparently) means that the increment must already have been performed, because `++x` is an lvalue.

Comment: @dyp Side-effects are not sequenced w.r.t their associated value computation. It is true that the value computation of `++x` is sequenced-before the side-effect of `=`, but not that the side-effect of `++x` is sequenced-before the side-effect of `=`.  Your logic would imply that `x = x++` is well-defined (which everyone agrees it isn't)

Comment: @dyp Quoting from DR637, "In order to value-compute the RHS (++i + 1), it is necessary to first value-compute the lvalue expression ++i **and then do an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the result**. This guarantees that the incrementation side-effect is sequenced before the computation of the addition operation".  In `i = ++i` it is not necessary to do the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion after the value computation of `++i` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ad first comment: The side-effect of `++x` is sequenced before the value computation of `++x`. This is not true for `x++`. The value computation both sides of `=`, including the RHS `++x`, is sequenced before the side-effect of `=`. As I said, when an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is required is not well-specified. I would guess that it is required for the RHS of `=`.

Comment: @dyp the RHS of `=` might not be an lvalue, so it can't require lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Certainly there is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion required to compute `++i` in order to find the initial value of `i` , but that is sequenced-before the value computation of `++i` (because that is defined as equivalent to `i += 1`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb equally either operand of binary `+` might not be an lvalue, but we agree (I think) that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs there.