# Dereference operator in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I am unable to get my head around what type of *value* does the deference operator accept as its argument. By *value*, here I mean is it *lvalue* or *rvalue*?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
int i = 1, *p = &i;
cout << *p++; // Prints 1, so far so good.
```

Now since postfix `++` returns the *unincremented value* (unlike its prefix counterpart which returns *incremented object*) of `p`, from the code above it appears that unary `*` accepts an rvalue as its only operand. But,

```
cout << *i;  // error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

Okay, maybe the value of `i` doesn't represent a valid memory address. Now to confirm that unary `*` can work on an rvalue that represents a valid memory location, I tried something like this:

```
unsigned long add = p;  // error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
cout << *add;           // error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

This also brings me to my next question. Assuming that the size of `unsigned long` is 64 bits (which happens to be true for the system I am working on), why is it not possible to copy the *value* stored in `p` (which happens to be a 64-bit memory address) into `add`? Or in other words, is there a way to store a memory address in a variable of non-pointer type (I would be surprised if this isn't possible because a memory address is after all also a value)?

Thanks

Comment: `*` can only be used on a pointer. Your codes `*i` and `*add` fail because `i` and `add` are integers, not pointers; nothing to do with value categories

Comment: Stop thinking about the number of bits. `int` and `double` might be both 123bits long, but are different types. `int` and `unsigned int` might be 62bits each but are different types. Pointers and integers are different types, even if both might have the same number of bits. In the vast majority of cases you don't need to convert pointers to integers or vice versa; this is a horrible code smell.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in dereference operator takes a prvalue, which *has to be of a pointer type*. If the operand is a glvalue, it will be subjected to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion prior to dereference.

If you want to convert between data pointer types and equivalent-sized integral types, you can, but you must say that that is what you want to do by using `reinterpret_cast`. This is to prevent errors, e.g. forgetting to dereference a pointer-to-int.

Comment: Where in standard is stated that built-in dereference operator  takes prvalue? First paragraph in 5.3.1 says that it takes pointer to object or pointer to function. It doesn't specify value category. I was able to use it also on xvalue: http://ideone.com/GT2Qm9 .

Comment: @PcAF see [conv.lval]/1. In a context where prvalue is required (such as the operand of `*`), a glvalue may be converted to prvalue

Comment: About xvalue, my bad, I thought that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applies to lvalues not glvalues. But question still remains. Which document are you reading? In [n4594](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) [conv.lval]/1 there isn't such sentence.

Comment: @PcAF [expr]/9: "Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, [...] standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue." The Standard doesn't appear to say when a prvalue is expected; this may be a defect.

Comment: @PcAF see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099769/regarding-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-when-is-it-required

Comment: You misunderstood me. I was asking where in standard is stated that *unary * operator* takes prvalue.

Comment: @PcAF that's what the question I linked to discusses; it appears that the language implying that operators take prvalues except where otherwise specified was lost between C++03 and C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a pointer type to a non-pointer type without an explicit cast (`reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast). Or the class should have implicit conversion operator. Assuming that `int` or `long` will fit a pointer type is wrong and risky assumption. If you take that risk, yes, you can store a pointer into a non-pointer type:

```
int main()
{    
    int a, b;
    a = 10;
    b = (int)&a;

    a = 40;
    cout << *(int*)b << endl;

    *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(b)) = 160;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```